Wooden windows, clean and repair
I just moved into this house that has a combination of old (1994) Pella and Andersen wooden windows. Seems previous owners didn’t take good care and there’s water stains and mold on the wood everywhere it meets glass. I read that glazing is done for outside but is there a compound/material/solution that I can use inside? I am planning on sanding, cleaning with bleach solution and staining the wood but would like to make sure the seal between glass and wood from inside the house is in good shape.
Any advice?

Please [edit] to include a pic of a window, then a close up pic showing us how the glass is mounted into the sash. You can drag and drop images directly into the text edit box, or you can click the "sun & mountain" button to upload images.

Those are modern wooden windows. Which the style at the time was to leave them naked and then this happens. +1.

These windows use a butyl type non hardening sealant between the wood stops and the glass.
In my opinion, removal, restoration and reinstallation of the wood stops is not worth the heartbreak of broken stops.
If the sealed units are in good condition, trim the excess sealant with a sharp knife, scrape away any residue, do your wood refinishing and apply a clear silicone heel bead around the perimeter between the wood stop and the glass.

Glazing means installing glass; I think you might mean reglazing.
With modern windows there's usually a gasket that seals the glass to the frame; with older windows that seal is made with glass "points" as the initial  mechanical support and glazier's putty as the final support and seal. Putty can dry out and fall off over time, losing that seal; websearch "reglazing windows" for details. More modern gasketing should have a longer life than putty.
Reglazing can be a DIY, but even pros sometimes break glass while cleaning out the old putty, so you might want  to make it their problem rather than yours. Window sashes can be dismounted and carried to a glass shop, if you want to DIY that part of the work; details depend on the window design.

These are Pella or Andersen windows. They would not have used the method you described. They may have used some type of butyl sealant or even closed cell neoprene. It's even possible that the glass is a physically double glazed unit with the interior glass panel removable. A picture would really help.

Photo added. Thank you
